# ifstream not opening filename from getopenfilename

Tags: c++, winapi, fstream

Amateur programmer here.  My problem today is that I am trying to load a .txt file in to be displayed in the edit box of a dialog box.

before I start with code: I can get it to work by SPECIFYING the file location and bypassing the load dialog from getopenfilename, and it works swimmingly.  But when i obtain that file location from getopenfilename, i can't seem to work it.

The relevant code is:

```
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = hDlg;
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;

ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
ofn.lpstrFilter = "All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == TRUE)
{
    hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile, GENERIC_READ, 0, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, (HANDLE)NULL);

    ifstream inFile(ofn.lpstrFile);

    if (!inFile)
        MessageBox(0, "CAN'T OPEN FILE", "ALERT", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
    else
    {
        string text;
        while(getline(inFile, text));
        inFile.close();

        MessageBox(0, text.c_str(), "msg", MB_OK);
        SetWindowText(editbox, text.c_str());
    }
    CloseHandle(hf);
    hf = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
```

I am a novice, but I have been wracking my brain and my google bar trying to figure this out.

It does not ever open via fstream.

Comment: Why do you try to open the file using both the Win32 APi and the C++ Standard Library?

Comment: _i can't seem to work it._ And.. What, **exactly** is the problem?

Comment: Apart from the original problem, you also have a bug in how you read the file. You will only display the last line of the file because each `getline()` call will overwrite the contents of the `text` variable.

Comment: There's a classic beginner's mistake here. You mix together two independent aspects. Your problem is with opening a file. You don't need a dialog to investigate that. Isolate the issue. Look just at the code that opens a file.

Answer (score 3):

The source of the problem is that you try to open the file with both Win32 API (`CreateFile()`) and with standard library (`std::ifstream`).

By looking at your `CreateFile()` call and at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), one can see that you are passing `0` to the `dwShareMode` argument, whose description states:

> If this parameter is zero and CreateFile succeeds, the file or device cannot be shared and cannot be opened again until the handle to the file or device is closed.

But, after that call, you proceed to try to open the file via `std::ifstream`, which fails due to the reason described above, and you are only checking if `ifstream` succeeds to open the file.

The issue can be avoided if you use only either `CreateFile()` or `std::ifstream`, not both.